# AngularJS date and time picker with custom input validation

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I would like to know if there is any angularjs component that provides me date/time picker + custom input date with keyboard??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you said AngularJS, I'm going to guess it's 1.x (2 and 4 do not have this JS suffix)
Checkout the [BootstrapUI](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/). They should have everything you mentioned, including keyboard support. Search for "datepicker" in the page as all their components are listed in a single page...

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/datepicker
There are some datetime picker with code

Comment: Thank you on your suggestion. Very helpful.